# jqXHR Status Code Mismatch

Tags: jquery, http, google-chrome-devtools

I am seeing a Status Code of `302` on the network tab of Chrome Dev Tools but getting `200` from within the `error` callback of the `ajax` request. Also how is it possible to get `200 success` from inside `error`?

[image: chrome-dev-tool]

Someone clear the air please.

Comment: have you used any redirection?

Comment: @rafi No redirection.